# Countdown timer needs some rounding down ? VB / Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I had this written for me.. It counts down to our next sale but the minutes don't change until the second drop to under 30. The hours don't change till the minutes drop to under 30 etc. I posted this some time ago but solution supplied was beyond me. I just wondered if anyone knew a way if the current code could be tweaked to work ?

```
    Dim seconds As Integer = DateDiff(DateInterval.Second, Date.Now, BootSale.nextDOW(DayOfWeek.Sunday))
    Dim days, hours, minutes As Integer
    days = seconds / 86400
    hours = (seconds Mod 86400) / 3600
    minutes = (seconds Mod 3600) / 60
    lblTimer.Text = days & " Day(s) " & hours & " Hour(s) " & minutes & " Minute(s) " ' & seconds Mod 60 & " Seconds"
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: @EricS I've tried the 2 suggestions below but no change. Can be seen running here.. http://www.onlinecarbooty.com/go-booting.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You should use proper .NET functions to do that. The [TimeSpa](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx)n structure already have the functionality that you need.

```
    Dim difference As TimeSpan = BootSale.nextDOW(DayOfWeek.Sunday).Subtract(DateTime.Now)

    Dim message As String = String.Format("{0} Day(s) {1} Hour(s) {2} Minute(s)", difference.Days, difference.Hours, difference.Minutes)

    lblTimer.Text = message
```

Comment: Many thanks, I tried this and it does the same thing. You can see what it does here.. http://www.onlinecarbooty.com/go-booting-front.aspx The counter is counting down to 3pm Sunday UK time.

Comment: I don't see the problem happening. Can you give me two datetime value and what you expect to see from their substraction?

Comment: As soon as the seconds reach 0, the minutes should be decreased by 1. Not happening this end.. It only does it when it passes 30-29 seconds then the minutes subtract 1. Same for hours and days etc.

Comment: @Eggybread I tried it again and it works well for me. You would have to give me a testcase that doesn't work. Can you give me two datetime value wnad what you expect to see?

Answer (score 0):

.Net is rounding these automatically as you don't have `option strict on`. You can use Math.Floor to always round down.

```
Dim seconds As Integer = DateDiff(DateInterval.Second, Date.Now, BootSale.nextDOW(DayOfWeek.Sunday))
Dim days, hours, minutes As Integer
days = Math.Floor(seconds / 86400)
hours = Math.Floor((seconds Mod 86400) / 3600)
minutes = Math.Floor((seconds Mod 3600) / 60)
lblTimer.Text = days & " Day(s) " & hours & " Hour(s) " & minutes & " Minute(s) " ' & seconds Mod 60 & " Seconds"
```

---

I've rewritten it as a function so you can see my test cases are working.

```
Public Function TestDate(d1 As DateTime, d2 As DateTime) As String
    Dim seconds As Integer = DateDiff(DateInterval.Second, d1, d2)
    Dim days, hours, minutes As Integer
    days = Math.Floor(seconds / 86400)
    hours = Math.Floor((seconds Mod 86400) / 3600)
    minutes = Math.Floor((seconds Mod 3600) / 60)
    Return days & " Day(s) " & hours & " Hour(s) " & minutes & " Minute(s) "
End Function

Assert.AreEqual("2 Day(s) 15 Hour(s) 45 Minute(s) ", TestDate(n, n.Add(New TimeSpan(2, 15, 45, 45))))
Assert.AreEqual("2 Day(s) 5 Hour(s) 5 Minute(s) ", TestDate(n, n.Add(New TimeSpan(2, 5, 5, 5))))
```

Comment: Many thanks, still does the same thing. You can see it here.. http://www.onlinecarbooty.com/go-booting-front.aspx I am using your code at the moment.

Comment: This seems to be a lot of overkill for something you could easily do on the client side with a little javascript. Just set a javascript timer to convert the dates. I've tried the code above in nunit and it was giving what I expected.

Comment: I know, I agree.. I've just never dabbled with javascript yet so wouldn't know how to pass variables to the script. The above would do the job if i could suss out why it only changes the minutes down when the seconds go below 30. Thanks again.

Comment: I've added the test case I used to validate that the code was working. I suspect you're not deploying it correctly.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still quite new to all this.. Where Do I put the Assert.AreEqual code ? This is the the front end ..

    <asp:Timer ID="timer1" runat="server" Interval="1000" OnTick="timer1_tick"></asp:Timer>

    <asp:UpdatePanel id="updPnl" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <h2 class="boldStyle">NEW Sale starts in <asp:Label ID="lblTimer" runat="server"></h2></asp:Label></h2>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="timer1" EventName="tick" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

Comment: Just create a new unit test library /console application / winforms application. You'll find that both answers to your post work if you run the code. So find any way you can of running it. The assert function is just something that compares 2 values and throws an exception if they don't match. Or just use your debugger, set a breakpoint where the function is called and inspect the values. Debugging is the most valuable thing you'll learn